# How to run a DB script before any commit in a Spring-JPA based project?

Tags: java, spring, oracle, hibernate, jpa-2.0

I want to call a stored procedure before any commit to database in a project that based on Spring and JPA.

Everytime I make an operation like update, remove or insert to any entity I want to execute a stored procedure.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: yuo may user JPA EventListeners. You may give a look here https://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/persistence/event

Comment: Thanks for the answer @A

Comment: Thanks for the answer @AngeloImmediata. But when I tried to call a stored procedure with entityListener I am taking an exception like "A soft-locked cache entry was expired by the underlying Ehcache. If this happens regularly you should consider increasing the cache timeouts and/or capacity limits". But I did not configure an ehcache configuration.

Comment: may you post your spring and hibernate configuration and some piece of code?

Comment: Hi again, It seems okay now. Thanks for your help.